# Is there any way I can simplify this?

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

I have two labels (Pay and Hours) that I want to multiply. I want an error box to show up when the user didn't put in a number but I can only figure out the easiest way to do it will be to make two if statements and do it that way. Any help would be great.

```
    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double hours = Double.Parse(tbxHours.Text);
        double pay = Double.Parse(tbxPay.Text);

        if (Double.TryParse(tbxPay.Text,  out pay))
            {
            double result = hours * pay;
            MessageBox.Show($" total amount is {result} ", "Click Event",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"You must enter a number", "Input Error",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            tbxPay.Clear();

        }


        if (Double.TryParse(tbxHours.Text, out hours))
        {
            double result = hours * pay;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"You must enter a number", "Input Error",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            tbxHours.Clear();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You're parsing twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to parse once per control.  Here's a simplification you can reuse for multiple controls containing numbers as text.

```
private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TryParseFromTextBox(tbxHours, out double hours) && 
        TryParseFromTextBox(tbxPay, out double pay))
    {
        double result = hours * pay;
        MessageBox.Show($" total amount is {result} ", "Click Event", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}

public bool TryParseFromTextBox(TextBox control, out double value)
{
    if (!double.TryParse(control.Text, out value))
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"You must enter a number in {control.Name}", "Input Error", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        control.Clear();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

A few extra things to consider.

- Should you focus on the control where the number parse fails?
- Should your `btnCalc` even be clickable if there are not valid numbers in these textboxes?

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I was trying to figure out how to add two variables to an if statement I forgot about &&